# Unable to connect to Samba share using smbclient - "tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I'm trying to connect to a Samba share on a remote machine (running Windows Server 2003) from my laptop (running Ubuntu 15.10). Using `smbclient` (Version 4.1.17-Ubuntu) I can see the share I am trying to connect to:

```
~$ smbclient -U myname%mypass -W mydomain -L //remote.address.com
Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Windows Server 2003 3790 Service Pack 2] Server=[Windows Server 2003 5.2]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        myshare         Disk      
        C$              Disk      Default share
        D$              Disk      Default share

        ...etc.

Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Windows Server 2003 3790 Service Pack 2] Server=[Windows Server 2003 5.2]
```

However if I try to connect I get the following error:

```
~$ smbclient -U myname%mypass -W mydomain -L //remote.address.com/myshare
Domain=[MYDOMAIN] OS=[Windows Server 2003 3790 Service Pack 2] Server=[Windows Server 2003 5.2]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
```

If I try to mount using `mount.cifs` I get:

```
~$ sudo mount -v -t cifs //remote.address.com/myshare /tmp/tmpmount -o username=myname,domain=mydomain,pass=mypass
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=163.1.10.2,unc=\\remote.address.com\myshare,user=myname,,domain=mydomain,pass=********
mount error(20): Not a directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I'm quite sure that my username/password/domain are all correct, and based on the output of `smbclient -L` I'm certain that the share I'm trying to connect to exists. Any idea what might cause these errors?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was server-side rather than client-side. There was an issue with the RAID configuration on the remote machine that was preventing Windows as well as Linux clients from mounting the share. Re-importing the affected virtual disk and rebooting the server resolved the problem.